# Share on Facebook using Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hi i am using **share on facebook** using **javascript**.

When i login to my app for the first time and on facebook from this code for the first time the it works perfect.I am able to share multiple times.

problem starts from here

If i logout from the app and again login then if i click on share button it does not opens popup.

Check my code and correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Below is my code.

```
function share(){

        var share = {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Real Prize Arcade',
        link: 'http://india-webdev.com/arcade/www/RPA.mp4',
        picture: 'http://india-webdev.com/arcade/www/images/arcade.png',            
        description: 'Real Prize Arcade',       
        source: 'https://www.youtube.com/v/1CE6W5BubQo'
        };

        FB.ui(share, function(response) { 
           if(response && response.post_id !== undefined) {
              alert('Successfully Shared');
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: Very little debugging information. how did you try to change the source, what source did you try (might be obvious but picture also has a source), which source did you try to change, what do you mean the second time, the second time you click? the second time you go to the website?

Comment: where/how do you load the SDK? That info is missing, and might be important...